# Deploy a simple test app with Sinatra + DataMapper + Postgres + Heroku returns: Installing do_sqlite3 (0.10.7) error

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, heroku, sinatra, datamapper

**Goal**: Deploy a simple test app with Sinatra + DataMapper + Postgres + Heroku

**Issue**: When using gem 'dm-postgres-adapter' gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter' to push the app to Heroku I get this.
Installing do_sqlite3 (0.10.7) with native extensions Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Thanks!

I have visited that github link and someone had the same issue but gets directed to Heroku, https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1488 . I have sent an email to the mailing list of Heroku and am waiting for a reply.

I ran into `LoadError: no such file to load -- dm-sqlite-adapter`
So I added that into the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock and this is as far as I can ever get

I have tried to instal and setup Postgres locally but thats brand new set of pains that i'm slowly learning but can not get to work yet.

I have also read each and every question here with a simular issue, some progressed me to this point and some dont have responses from the asker and leave it a mystery.

## Gemfile

```
-----------------
source :rubygems
gem 'sinatra', '1.1.0'
gem 'thin', '1.2.7'
gem 'data_mapper'
gem 'dm-postgres-adapter'
gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter'
```

## Gemfile.lock

```
------------------------
...
dm-sqlite-adapter (1.2.0)
  dm-do-adapter (~> 1.2.0)
  do_sqlite3 (~> 0.10.6)
...
```

## Procfile

```
--------------------
web: bundle exec ruby recall.rb -p $PORT
```

## Recall.rb

```
---------------------
require 'rubygems'  
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'

DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/recall.db")


class Note
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :content, Text, :required => true
    property :complete, Boolean, :required => true, :default => 0
    property :created_at, DateTime
    property :updated_at, DateTime
end

DataMapper.auto_upgrade!

get '/' do
    @notes = Note.all :order => :id.desc
    @title = 'All Notes'
    erb :home
end
```

## Notes

```
-------------------------
10.7 Lion
Xcode 4 is installed
sqlite3 installed by Homebrew


~ which sqlite3
  
/usr/bin/sqlite3

~ gem list sql
sqlite3 (1.3.5)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)

~ gem list do_sqlite3
do_sqlite3 (0.10.7)

~ brew info sqlite3
sqlite 3.7.9
http//sqlite.org/
Depends on: readline
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.7.9 (9 files, 1.9M)
http//github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/sqlite.rb
```

## Error Log

```
------------------------------
~ rubyfish2 git:(master) git push heroku master
Counting objects: 22, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 2.42 KiB, done.
Total 15 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.rc.7

Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment

Fetching gem metadata from http//rubygems.org/.........

Using addressable (2.2.6)

Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)

Using daemons (1.1.5)

Using dm-core (1.2.0)

Using dm-aggregates (1.2.0)

Using dm-constraints (1.2.0)

Using dm-migrations (1.2.0)

Using fastercsv (1.5.4)

Using json (1.6.4)

Using json_pure (1.6.4)

Using multi_json (1.0.4)

Using dm-serializer (1.2.1)

Using dm-timestamps (1.2.0)

Using dm-transactions (1.2.0)

Using stringex (1.3.0)

Using uuidtools (2.1.2)

Using dm-types (1.2.1)

Using dm-validations (1.2.0)

Using data_mapper (1.2.0)

Using data_objects (0.10.7)

Using dm-do-adapter (1.2.0)

Using do_postgres (0.10.7)

Using dm-postgres-adapter (1.2.0)

Installing do_sqlite3 (0.10.7) with native extensions Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https//github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Thanks!

/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb

checking for sqlite3.h... no

*** extconf.rb failed ***

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of

necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more

details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:

--with-opt-dir

--without-opt-dir

--with-opt-include

--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include

--with-opt-lib

--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib

--with-make-prog

--without-make-prog

--srcdir=.

--curdir

--ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby

--with-sqlite3-dir

--without-sqlite3-dir

--with-sqlite3-include

--without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include

--with-sqlite3-lib

--without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/do_sqlite3-0.10.7 for inspection.

Results logged to /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/do_sqlite3-0.10.7/ext/do_sqlite3/gem_make.out

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `block in build_extensions'

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `each'

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `build_extensions'

from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in `install'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:90:in `block in install'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:82:in `preserve_paths'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:89:in `install'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:73:in `block in install_gem_from_spec'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:97:in `with_build_args'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:72:in `install_gem_from_spec'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:56:in `block in run'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:12:in `install'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'

from /tmp/build_1ikvsvr378qb6/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.rc.7/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'

from vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/bundle:19:in `load'

from vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Comment: Did you try removing the sqlite gem? It won't install on Heroku because sqlite isn't installed on heroku. You don't need it for production (heroku).

Answer (score 12):

The error when installing `do_sqlite` (`Installing do_sqlite3 (0.10.7) with native extensions...`) is simply because this gem requires the sqlite3 libraries to be installed, and they are not on Heroku. To fix it, remove `dm-sqlite-adapter` (which is what idepends on `do_sqlite`) from your Gemfile. If you want to keep Sqlite for development and use Postgres for production, you can use [Gembundler's groups](http://gembundler.com/groups.html):

```
gem 'dm-postgres-adapter', :group => :production
gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter', :group => :development
```

This way, the postgresql adapter will be installed in production on Heroku, but sqlite will be used locally for development.

The line in your code that sets up Datamapper is:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/recall.db")
```

This looks for a environment variable `DATABASE_URL` and if it's present uses it otherwise uses the sqlite url.  Getting the `LoadError: no such file to load -- dm-sqlite-adapter` error suggests that this variable isn't actually set. Run `heroku config`, there should be entries for `DATABASE_URL` and `SHARED_DATABASE_URL`. If they are not set you need to add the database.

Have a look at [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912738/sinatra-heroku-datamapper-deploy-issues-with-dm-sqlite-adapter) which deals with a similar issue. The solution there was to run `heroku addons:add shared-database:5mb`.