# Sinatra + Heroku + Datamapper deploy issues with dm-sqlite-adapter

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, datamapper

For some reason, heroku tries to require dm-sqlite-adapter, even though it should use Postgres here. Note, that this happens when I open any URL - not during the git push itself.

I built a default facebook app.

The Gemfile:

```
source :gemcutter

gem "foreman"

gem "sinatra"
gem "mogli"
gem "json"
gem "httparty"
gem "thin"
gem "data_mapper"
gem "heroku"

group :production do
    gem "pg"
    gem "dm-postgres-adapter"
end

group :development, :test do
    gem "sqlite3"
    gem "dm-sqlite-adapter"
end
```

Datamapper setup:

```
# Setting up the database
DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/data/mydatabase.db")
```

Relevant log fragment, when any URL is opened:

```
Starting process with command `bundle exec thin -R config.ru start -p 34984`
2012-01-18T15:11:55+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in `require': no such file to load -- dm-sqlite-adapter (LoadError)
2012-01-18T15:11:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in `load_adapter'
```

Tried related solutions, but with no help so far.

BTW: `bundle install` says `Using do_postgres` and `Using dm-postgres-adapter`. Am I missing something about Datamapper setup?

Comment: Try setting a config var of `BUNDLE_WITHOUT` with the value of `development:test` and see what happens

Comment: I guess it's already run when I issue `git push heroku master`:
`Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment`

Comment: Can you use Postgres locally?  It's really a good idea: http://www.12factor.net/dev-prod-parity

Comment: Nice site, haven't seen this before. TBH, the whole point was to make a mock-up application, making use of the simplest path. Now I'm just wasting time tinkering with dm adapters, instead of getting things done.

Comment: This suggests the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable somehow isn't set. Have you removed it? Does it show up when you run `heroku config`?

Comment: That was a brilliant suggestion! Details in the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, too many Rails apps on Heroku, I took the shared db presence for granted. `heroku config` showed neither `DATABASE_URL` or `SHARED_DATABASE_URL` set.

Issuing `heroku addons:add shared-database:5mb` solved the problem.

Strange, that the db wasn't automatically added, despite having 'pg' gem in Gemfile.

Quote from http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar:

> A Heroku shared PostgreSQL database (`shared-database:5mb`) will be
>   automatically added to your app in any of the following cases:
>
> - The app is a Rails application
> - The `pg` gem is specified in the `Gemfile`

Comment: Odd, I have seen this once before, but never been able to replicate it

Comment: Hey guys, this didn't happen to me when I used Active Record, but happened when I used DataMapper. Also I'm on a free account so I had to use `heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql`

Answer (score 3):

Try doing `DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres://user:password@hostname/data/mydatabase.db')` instead. Heroku is probably looking at the protocol, and therefore requiring SQLite’s dependencies.

Comment: I thought this as well, but I changed my code to wrap my code in configure statements and it still did the same thing.`configure :development do
  DataMapper.setup(:default,"sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/recall.db")
end

configure :production do
  DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
end` Also, I would assume the snippet reads `ENV['DATABASE_URL'] = true` and doesn't evaluate the RHS of the or statement.